# Query to search for values ​inside an array object

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have this object in my mongo. Inside the "conditions.all" array there is a list of objects with the fields fact, operator and value. I need a query to find the document in which the year value inside the object that has fact: "year", for example, in this case, the value 1970, compare whether this value is greater or less than an input value

```
{
      "_id": { "$oid": "5fc14323bd1f87002e8ca7ac" },
      "priority": { "$numberInt": "6" },
      "type": "pricing",
      "name": "BLOCK AUDI A6",
      "conditions": {
        "all": [
          { "fact": "brand", "operator": "equal", "value": "AUDI" },
          { "fact": "model", "operator": "equal", "value": "A6" },
          {
            "fact": "version",
            "operator": "in",
            "value": [
              "3.0 TFSI QUATTRO V6 24V GASOLINA 4P TIPTRONIC",
              "2.0 TFSI AMBIENTE GASOLINA 4P S-TRONIC",
              "3.0 TFSI ALLROAD 24V GASOLINA 4P S-TRONIC",
              "3.0 TFSI QUATTRO V6 24V GASOLINA 4P S-TRONIC"
            ]
          },
          {
            "fact": "km",
            "operator": "greaterThanInclusive",
            "value": { "$numberInt": "0" }
          },
          {
            "fact": "km",
            "operator": "lessThanInclusive",
            "value": { "$numberInt": "1000000" }
          },
          {
            "fact": "year",
            "operator": "greaterThanInclusive",
            "value": { "$numberInt": "1970" }
          }
        ]
      },...
```

I am currently using a query that checks the value inside the entire array, like this:

```
this.getCollection().aggregate({ $match: {"conditions.all.value":{$lte:2050} } })
```

but now i need to check the value inside the object specified by the fact field

Answer (score 0):

I think this query can be helpful for this question:-

`this.getCollection().aggregate({$match:{$and:[{"conditions.all.fact":"year"}, {"condition.all.value":{$or:[{$lte:1970},{$gte:1970}]}}]}})`